# Starting apache2 with custom httpd.conf

Tags: apache2, httpd.conf

Is there a way how to start apache using apachectl and passing a path to a non-default httpd.conf to it? I would like to avoid messing with the standard config files. I know I will have to start it as root nevertheless, but It would help me to play around.

Answer (score 0):

`apachectl` does not provide functionality for using custom config file. You have to execute `httpd` itself in order to do that.

Answer (score 0):

according to https://www.techrepublic.com/blog/linux-and-open-source/control-apache-with-the-apachectl-command/ this is done with the -f parameter.

Example:

```
# apachectl -f /etc/httpd/conf/httpd-testing.conf
```